# Value present in not-null constraint column but Postgres throws Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, postgresql-11

Today I have updated my project to DotNetCore 2.2. Since then, I am getting not-null constraint column error from Npgsql.PostgresException, even though values are present.

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 23502: null value in column "ItemCode"
>   violates not-null constraint

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostItem([FromBody] JObject data)
        {
            PKTable pkt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PKTable>(data["pkd"].ToString());
            List<FKTable> fkts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FKTable>>(data["fkd"].ToString());

            pkt.itemCode = "ABCD"; // Primary Key Column
            _context.PKTables.Add(pkt);
            try
            {
                if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0) // PKTable
                {
                    fkt.ForEach(u => { u.itemCode = item.itemCode; }); // Data present here in debug
                    _context.FKTables.AddRange(fkts);  // Data present here in debug
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // Throws error.
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            { throw; }

            return Ok(new { r = item.itemCode });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are filling fkt but

```
_context.FKTables.AddRange(fkts); <-- this is fkts.
```

I believe that you have logical mistake here.

Comment: Deployed API working as expected. We have not updated this controller, post update to v2.2

Answer (score 0):

I mapped foreign key as `[ForeignKey("ItemCode")]`. Now, changed this as `[ForeignKey("itemCode")]`.

Its working now. I wounder why it worked in earlier version that is Core 2.1.